# Laravel 4.2 Simple Session Logic not working

Tags: php, session, laravel

This is very simple session logic. I don't know why this isn't working. Here the code.

```
if(Session::get('sign_up_data')){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 2;
    Session::put('sign_up_data',21);
}
exit;
```

Always echoing 2 every time i reload the page. I am expecting echoing 2 on first load then the next 1 and 1 and 1 and soon. Tried different approach but still getting the same result. Do you any idea guys?

Comment: tried `has` instead `get` ?

Comment: Already did. but still getting the same result

Comment: i can get the value of sign_up_data if i echo it under session::put();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you kill the application mid-cycle (through `exit`, `dd`, etc.), the session data won't write. Remove the `exit`, and you are good.

If you need to kill the script mid-cycle, then save the session data manually. So, in other words, this works:

```
if(Session::get('sign_up_data')){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 2;
    Session::put('sign_up_data',21);
}
// exit;
```

If you are going to kill the script, then call `save` manually like this:

```
if(Session::get('sign_up_data')){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 2;
    Session::put('sign_up_data',21);
    Session::save();
}
exit;
```

Comment: Very well. Before i read your answer. i actually found to make it work  by removing the exit but i don't have ideas why it works. Then you clearly explain the how it works! Thank man!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your config for the session driver isn't set to `array`. Arrays aren't persistent.
2. Use chrome/firefox dev tools  to check that a session cookie is being created and is the same every time you reload

As a final point you can simplify you code to use the default response feature (which will not solve your problem but is better code)/